# XPath получить все элементы <script> находящиеся между </div> и </body>

Tags: php, xpath

Помогите получить с помощью XPath все элементы `<script>` находящиеся между `</div>` и `</body>`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://kakoytodomen.ru/script0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var peremennaya;
        </script>

        <div>Куча всего
            <div><script type="text/javascript">
                    var peremennaya;
                </script>
                еще какая то куча</div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://kakoytodomen.ru/script1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://kakoytodomen.ru/script2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://kakoytodomen.ru/script3.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//body/script[not(following-sibling::*[not(name() = 'script')])]
```

он ищет такие `script` под `body`, за которыми нет тэгов, отличных от `script`

`*[not(name() = 'script')]` - это тэги не `script`

`not(following-sibling::*[not(name() = 'script')` - такого нет после и на том же уровне

За первым script присутствуют другие тэги до окончания `body` - он не подходит

Comment: Вы мой спаситель! Спасибо. Идеально работает. Да интересно было бы понять как работает.

Comment: я чутка написал, если что-то непонятно, спросите, напишу подробнее

Comment: Почему запрос отработал правильно и в результат не попал скрипт который идет сразу после открывающего тега body?.

Comment: в ответе написал

Comment: Все теперь понял. Спасибо огромное!